# $ C_{MRB}=\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } (-1)^x\left(e^{\frac{\log x}{x}}-1\right)$ Is its absolutely convergent arrangement prime number theorem related?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, prime-gaps, conditional-convergence

$ C_{MRB}=\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } (-1)^x\left(e^{\frac{\log  x}{x}}-1\right)$  Is its absolutely convergent neighbor prime number theorem related?

$ C_{MRB}=\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } (-1)^x\left(e^{\frac{\log  x}{x}}-1\right)=\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } (-1)^x \left(e^{\frac{\log (x)}{x}}-\frac{\log (x)}{x}-1\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \gamma  \log (2)-\log ^2(2)\right).$

where $ C_{MRB}$ is the MRB constant and $\gamma$ is Euler's Gamma constant. Is that equivalence of the two series prime number theorem related?

I've been studying the series,

$C_{MRB}=\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } (-1)^x\left(e^{\frac{\log  x}{x}}-1\right)$

It's all well and good, but I never liked the fact that it is only conditionally convergent.
To my relieve the Late Richard Crandall discovered a way of converting it to an absolutely convergent one:
$$ C_{MRB}=\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } (-1)^x \left(e^{\frac{\log (x)}{x}}-\frac{\log (x)}{x}-1\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \gamma  \log (2)-\log ^2(2)\right) $$

I can tell that the new series is absolutely convergent because the series of its sequences' absolute values converges. So that is not my question.

I might be overthinking it, but I wonder if he had the prime counting function in mind when he derived the absolutely convergent series? Or would that be useful in further study about the MRB constant? An GPT-4 search produced the phrase "Abscissa of absolute convergence."

The reason for my madness is that the prime counting function is as x-> infinity, $\pi( x)=\frac{x}{log(x)}$. And the term he added to the continually convergent series is its inverse, which coincidental (or not) is also the exponent on $e.$

Comment: No. The equivalence is about making the terms tend to $0$ quadratically instead of linearly by carving out the linear term of $e^u$'s Taylor series from the summands. The fact $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is present is because the original series has it to begin with. Also $\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}$ is an asymptotic, not an equality. Something having $\frac{x}{\log x}$ (or its reciprocal) in it does not suggest it is number theory related.

Comment: @elemelons: I started to figure it out, but can you explain, "The equivalence is about making the terms tend to 0 quadratically instead of linearly by carving out the linear term of e^u's Taylor series from the summands." I'm sure you can explain it better that I can. I see in Mathematica, the Series[E^(Log[x]/x), {x, Infinity, n}] is the sum of ( log(x)/x)^n/n!

Comment: You know the terms of your series tend to zero. But how fast? Setting $u=\frac{\log x}{x}$, you have $(e^u-1)\sim u$ tends to $0$ "linearly." And $(e^u-1-u)\sim\frac{1}{2}u^2$ tends to $0$ "quadratically." Linear doesn't give us absolute convergence the way quadratic does. How did they know to subtract $u$ from $e^u-1$ to get quadratic decay? Well, because $e^u=1+u+\frac{1}{2}u^2+\cdots$ is the Taylor series for $e^u$ around $u=0$. (The series $\sum_{x=1}^\infty(-1)^x\frac{\log x}{x}=\gamma(\log2)-\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2$ they carved out of the original is *itself* conditionally convergent, BTW)

Comment: I do not see a reason for manipulating with $a_n=e^{\log n\over n}-1.$ The sequence $a_n$ is positive, decreasing for $n\ge 3$ and convergent to $0.$  Hence by the Leibniz  test the series $\sum (-)^na_n$ is convergent.

Comment: @
Ryszard Szwarc
:  My reason for further manipulation was that 
 the Riemann series theorem states that, by a suitable rearrangement of terms, a conditionally convergent series may be made to converge to any desired value, or to diverge. I looked at that as something critical about $C_{MRB}$ since it is a "constant."

Comment: @ 
elemelons: Thank you1 To find where I used it CNTL+f " 
The MRB constant relates to the divergent series" at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628