# How would you prove $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{1/n}+\eta '(n)-\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}-1\right)+\eta '(1) =$ the MRB constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, absolute-convergence

The step I'm having trouble with is

$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{1/n}+\eta '(n)-\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}-1\right)+\eta '(1)
=-\left(\sum _{m=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m  \eta ^m(m)}{m!}+\eta '(1)\right)$

Expounding upon the MRB constant, I found the following equation, where I go in steps from a single conditionally to a single absolutely convergent sequence. I can compute and analyze each line using Mathematica, but I would like to present something more elegant than that at my discussion in https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628.

(In part, I added and subtracted the following conditionally convergent series, $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \eta'(n) =\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}\right) $$ but I thought there would be a rigorous way to show their equality is correct. I also combined that with the comment I got in [$ C_{MRB}=\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } (-1)^x\left(e^{\frac{\log x}{x}}-1\right)$ Is its absolutely convergent arrangement prime number theorem related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721210/c-mrb-sum-x-1-infty-1x-lefte-frac-log-xx-1-right-is-it) ,

You know the terms of your series tend to zero. But how fast? Setting $u=\frac{\log x}{x}$, you have $(e^u-1)\sim u$ tends to $0$ "linearly." And $(e^u-1-u)\sim\frac{1}{2}u^2$ tends to $0$ "quadratically." Linear doesn't give us absolute convergence the way quadratic does. How did they know to subtract $u$ from $e^u-1$ to get quadratic decay? Well, because $e^u=1+u+\frac{1}{2}u^2+\cdots$ is the Taylor series for $e^u$ around $u=0$. (The series $\sum_{x=1}^\infty(-1)^x\frac{\log x}{x}=\gamma(\log2)-\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2$ they carved out of the original is *itself* conditionally convergent, BTW),

where I repeated the carving out indefinitely to get the term, $\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}.$ used above.)

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)$$
$$=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{1/n}-\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}-1\right)+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \eta'(n) $$
$$=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{1/n}+\eta '(n)-\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}-1\right)+\eta '(1)$$
$$=-\left(\sum _{m=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m  \eta ^m(m)}{m!}+\eta '(1)\right)$$
$$=-\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m  \eta ^m(m)}{m!}$$

$ \eta(m)$ is the Dirichlet eta function

Here is most of the work I did "where I repeated the carving out indefinitely:" [image]

Gottfried Helms gave this beautiful proof to get the last sum from the first, but I would like to see it proved step by step.

The first equality can be reproduced by formally stating the double sum: write down the expanded exponantial series for each term in one row, sum then column-wise to get the derivatives of the $\eta()$ and sum then the $\eta()$-expressions. Here the $\eta(s)$ is the alternating $\zeta(s)$ and $\eta^{(m)}(s)$ the $m$'th derivative.

$$ \begin{array} {rclll} 
 -\exp( {\log(1) \over 1})+1 & = & -{\log(1) \over 1} 
                                   &-{\log(1)^2 \over 1^2 2!}
                                   &-{\log(1)^3 \over 1^3 3!} & - \cdots \\
 +\exp( {\log(2) \over 2})-1 & = &+{\log(2) \over 2} 
                                   &+{\log(2)^2 \over 2^2 2!}
                                   &+{\log(2)^3 \over 2^3 3!} & + \cdots \\
 -\exp( {\log(3) \over 3})+1 & = &-{\log(3) \over 3} 
                                   &-{\log(3)^2 \over 3^2 2!}
                                   &-{\log(3)^3 \over 3^3 3!} & - \cdots \\
    \vdots \qquad                  & \vdots & \quad\vdots & \quad\vdots& \quad\vdots
         & \ddots \\
\hline \\
    B \qquad & = &   {\eta^{(1)}(1) \over 1!} 
                  &- {\eta^{(2)}(2) \over 2!} 
                  &+ {\eta^{(3)}(3) \over 3!} & - \cdots
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best proof I have. There could be some errors in it.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)
\\
=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{1/n}-\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}-1\right)+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \eta'(n) 
\\
=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{1/n}+\eta '(n)-\frac{\log (n)}{n-1}-1\right)+\eta '(1)$$

\begin{array} {rclll} 
 \eta'(1) & = & -{\log(1) \over 1} 
                                   &+{\log(1)^2 \over 2}
                                   &-{\log(1)^3 \over 3} & + \cdots \\
 +2^{1/2}+\eta'(2)-{\log(n)\over(n-1)}-1 & = & a2+{\log(2) \over 2} 
                                   &-{\log(2)^2 \over 2^2 2!}
                                   &+{\log(2)^3 \over 2^3 3!} & - \cdots \\
 -3^{1/3}-\eta'(3)+{\log(n)\over(n-1)}+1 & = &a3-{\log(3) \over 3} 
                                   &+{\log(3)^2 \over 3^2 2!}
                                   &-{\log(3)^3 \over 3^3 3!} & + \cdots \\
 +4^{1/4}+\eta'(4)-{\log(n)\over(n-1)}-1 & = &a4+{\log(4) \over 4} 
                                   &{\log(4)^2 \over 4^2 2!}
                                   &+{\log(4)^3 \over 4^3 3!} & - \cdots \\
    \vdots \qquad                  & \vdots & \quad\vdots & \quad\vdots& \quad\vdots
         & \ddots,\text{  }  {a2+a3+a4+...=0}\\
\hline \\
    CMRB \qquad & = &   +{\eta^{(1)}(1) \over 1!} 
                  &- {\eta^{(2)}(2) \over 2!} 
                  &+ {\eta^{(3)}(3) \over 3!} & - \cdots
\end{array}
\
$$=-\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m  \eta ^m(m)}{m!}$$